# To place obejects relatively horizanly

Tags: html, css

i have a `<div>` and another `<div>` i want the second `div` to be placed relatively to the other `div` but not under it, instead i want it to be right of it.

I want the second `div` to start exacly right of where the first `div` ends.  I dont want to use `position:absolute` because I dont know where the first `div` will end.

How can i do that? if possible please update this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S2r28/

Thanks for the help :D

EDIT: i want it to be right of it not left, my fault

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S2r28/1/ ?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to do... You should get at look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp . Blocks and inline elements are not the same!
But if you want your div to be placed like you said, use some `float : left;`, `display:inline;`... Or use something else than divs ;)

Comment: Float: left; or display:block;

Comment: @Luhof http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: alright i did with display, that worked Tnx

Comment: `float:left` can help

Answer (score 0):

Try this , give style for div

```
div
{
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that's impossible with this HTML setup.

Instead you have to add a div that contains the 2 divs, give that the position you desire and then make both div's `float:left;` so that they are aligned next to each others.

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:31%; left:20%;">
    <div style="float:left;">First Div</div>
    <div style="float:left;">Second Div</div>
</div>
```

[Your JSFiddle ~ updated by Daan Heskes](http://jsfiddle.net/S2r28/2/)